# Where Should I start in regards to making music?

Tags: guitar, piano, beginner, mixing

I have been studying music theory on and off for 2 years. I am 21 now and I have always had a love for music and was involved in school activities for music up until 6th grade. I unfortunately had to drop all music curriculums because I was an IEP student and my mother and father could not find the time to let me attend choir concert or partake in outside of school clubs and activities because they were going through a divorce. I have since lost most if not all of my basic knowledge in regards to the basics of music such as reading notes and terminology. I would really like to make music and most of the terms and definitions I know now are related to DAWs but I have no common knowledge on playing instruments or reading notes of any kind. I am not sure if I can progress at this rate at my age and not knowing who to go to. Any advice? Should I pick up an instrument first or study notes and how to read them?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this question is well suited to the format of this site.  But picking up an instrument is never a bad idea if you want to make music.

Comment: Also, check out these answers w.r.t your age https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/76066/can-one-be-too-old-to-learn-an-instrument

Comment: Yes, this question is opinion based. My person opinion is to start taking lessons on a musical instrument and keep studying or go back to studying music theory also. In terms of what instrument to pick, you could base it on the type of music you want to make. For example, if you want to make rock songs, then guitar, bass, or drums are good options. If you want to compose for symphony orchestra or create EDM tracks, then piano would be a good choice. Really any instrument will help you a lot with making your own music.

Comment: Hi, thank you guys for the quick supportive feedback. Sorry if it doesn't make much sense to ask it here on this site but I appreciate the positive support and feedback regardless.

Comment: To my experience don‘t worry about your age. If you learned to learn, e.g. by staying curious, age won‘t keep you from making quick progress. E.g. try linking your DAW experience with music theory, from memory, books you may have access to, or dedicated websites. // You could e.g. ask yourself: It looks like this in a DAW … how would it appear on sheet notes? Which key is it? Recalling X from music theory, how to apply it in your DAW? And so on. Q leads to A, perhaps via research. That‘s applied learning.

Comment: Age is irrelevant. Choose an instrument, find a teacher, and learn theory through those two. You'll be able to relate what you learn back to DAW-speak eventually.